# POST com AngularJS e Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, angular, post

Estou tentando enviar via POST para meu backend laravel, porem no console ele aponta o erro:

> POST http://localhost:8000/novo 500 (Internal Server Error) ! !

- Aqui está meu codigo do AngularJS

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <style type="text/css">
      .top50{
          margin-top: 50px;
      }
  </style>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

      <div class="container">
          <form ng-submit="enviar()">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                      <input type="" ng-model="pedido.total" name="nome">
                      {{nome}}
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                      <input type="" ng-model="pedido.quantidade_produtos" name="email">
                      {{user}}
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </form>
          {{pedido}}
          <table class="table top50">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <td>ID</td>
                      <td>Total</td>
                      <td>Qnt. Produtos</td>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat="t in teste">
                      <td>{{t.id}}</td>
                      <td>{{t.total}}</td>
                      <td>{{t.quantidade_produtos}}</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>    
      </div>
  </div>


  <script>


  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.pedido= {};

       $scope.enviar = function(){
          $http({
              url: 'http://localhost:8000/novo',
              method: "POST",
              data: $scope.pedido
          })
          .then(function(response) {
                  // success
          }, 
          function(response) { // optional
                  // failed
          });
      }



    $http.get("http://localhost:8000/angular")
    .then(function(response) {    
    setTimeout(function () {
          $scope.$apply(function () {
             $scope.teste = response.data;
          });
      }, 0);


    });
  });
  </script>
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- Esse é meu backend:

  ```
      public function adiciona(Request $request){

      Pedidos::create($request->all());

  }
  ```

Comment: Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Viu o que acontece na Aba "Network" do console do seu navegador? Só com esses dados é impossível dizer o que aconteceu, pois erro 500 pode ser n coisas diferentes.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta, por gentileza. E acrescente mais informações a respeito do erro.